# Click all buttons with same class

Tags: javascript, button, console, click

i've been trying to click all buttons with the same class class on a page after 10 seconds .This is in the google console.

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 10000);

function myTimer() {
 var items = document.getElementsByClassName('button-play');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
{      
  items[i].click();
}
}
```

problem is that it only clicks on the first 2 buttons then it goes back to the first in a loop
it skips the rest of the buttons on the page

Comment: post the html too

Comment: In the google console

Answer (score 0):

You can share your HTML code so that we can check if there is any mistakes in your HTML or JavaScript code.

You can try your code in below format. This is working for me:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button type="button" class="button-play" onclick="buttonClicked('Play1');"> Play1 </button>
        <button type="button" class="button-play" onclick="buttonClicked('Play2');"> Play2 </button>
        <button type="button" class="button-play" onclick="buttonClicked('Play3');"> Play3 </button>
    </body>
    <script>
        var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 10000);

        function myTimer() {
            console.log(new Date());
            var items = document.getElementsByClassName('button-play');
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {      
                items[i].click();
            }
        }
        function buttonClicked(text) {
            console.log(text);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: it clicks all the buttons without an interval but clicks the last button every 10 seconds in a loop... this is without the html as i'm using google console

Comment: This is strange. I am afraid but you need to share your HTML code (Buttons with same class) structure to answer your question.

Comment: I'm using the google console and pasting the code if i put html in i get an error.. it just just plays all buttons without any interval except the last one which it plays for 1 second then it starts over again

Comment: In your order to click the buttons, you must be having a web page where these buttons are being displayed. How you have created buttons in google console??

Comment: You can try creating one HTML file and copy paste all the code in it and then open the file using Google chrome to test it.

Comment: It is working fine for me...Check the updated code and output image in my answer.

Comment: tested u're code ..they all play at once ..all three buttons ..then again ..no gap

Comment: That is what you want, right? Or you want to play them with some time interval between them?

Comment: i want an interval between them of 10 seconds

Comment: Then you can add one more `setInterval` inside for loop.

Comment: and where do i add that please :)